# Error: 1 was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

So I'm making a game based on making decisions using notepad ++ and batch. I'm new to this and I have no idea what the problem is here.

```
:start 
;startup
cls
echo Wine or Cheese?
echo.
echo 1. Wine
echo 2. Cheese
echo 3. Exit
echo.
set /p input0=Enter: 
if %input0% equ 1 goto winestart
if %input0% equ 2 goto cheese
if %input0% equ 3 goto exit
```

When I select winestart or 1, it goes to winestart for a splitsecond then crashes, with the error message: 1 was unexpected at this time.
Winestart looks like this:

```
:winestart
cls
echo You are alone. You have a bottle of wine and the clothes you are wearing.
echo What kind of wine do you have?
echo.
echo 1. Red Wine
echo 2. White Wine
set p/ input7=Enter:

if %input7% equ 1 goto redwine
if %input7% equ 2 goto whitewine
```

Comment: Also, entering 2 (or going to cheese) works fine, and the code is practically identical. Entering 3 leads you nowhere and thus crashes it, but that's kinda the point.

Comment: Under :winestart, `set p/` should be `set /p`.

Answer (score 1):

`/p` indicates that the variable is simply set by user input. –

[SET](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

```
:winestart
cls
echo You are alone. You have a bottle of wine and the clothes you are wearing.
echo What kind of wine do you have?
echo.
echo 1. Red Wine
echo 2. White Wine
set /p input7=Enter:

if %input7% equ 1 goto redwine
if %input7% equ 2 goto whitewine
```

[Edit: Correct cure, but no explanation of *why* the error message appears]

Since `input7` is not entered, the `if` statement is interpreted as

```
if equ 1 goto redwine
```

`cmd` expects `if something equ anotherthing dosomething` so it sees `1` as the comparison-operator. This is not one of the operators it recognises, so it responds that the `1` is unexpected.

A better form of this is

```
if /i "%input7%" equ "1" goto redwine
```

where the `/i` forces a case-insensitive comparison and "quoting the arguments" preserves the syntax requirement where the user enters *nothing* or a string containing spaces (you have no control over the user's response.)

Comment: No, `/p` indicates that the variable is simply set by user input.