# CHOICE returning error

Tags: batch-file

**Problem**
I have 2 folders (each contain one file), and I am trying to copy the files from one to the other. The CHOICE command I have written works properly; however, after an answer is chosen the program closes immediately (no matter what choice is selected). A line was displayed "1 was unexpected at this time" as it was closing.

**My Code**

```
ECHO. & CHOICE /C:123 /N /M "Copy? (1. Copy 2. Exit 3. No Choice)" & ECHO.
::assigns choice values for user

IF /i %errorlevel1% EQU 1 GOTO copy
IF /i %errorlevel2% EQU 2 GOTO end
IF /i %errorlevel3% EQU 3 GOTO no_choice
::based on selection, redirects to logic

:copy
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO You chose to COPY the files... Hit any key to START or ctrl-z to CANCEL.
PAUSE > NUL
SET src_folder=d:\batch
SET dst_folder=d:\newBatch
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (batch.txt) DO (
xcopy /S/E/U "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%")
GOTO end
::offers cancel; if continue, copies files from batch to newBatch

:end
EXIT
::ends program

:no_choice
ECHO No action has been performed...
PAUSE
EXIT
::print message; then ends program
```

**Research**
I have searched all over the web, as well as some of this site's posts, and it helped me construe what I currently have here. The most recent Stack Overflow post I reviewed over this topic was found here ([Error: 1 was unexpected at this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155746/error-1-was-unexpected-at-this-time)). I implemented the "/i" fix that was mentioned in this post, but the individual asking the question was simply validating ECHO statements rather than CHOICE.

**Question**

- I am confused as to where this error is occurring since there are no   debugging features that I'm aware of in Batch programming, and the program closes immediately at the point of error. **(is the CHOICE statement wrong, or is the subsequent logic causing this problem?)**
- Should I avoid the CHOICE method and handle this process similarly to the post I referenced? **(is validating ECHO better than using CHOICE in this case?)**

Thanks!

Comment: The name of "errorlevel" feature does NOT include any digit: `IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 GOTO copy`

Comment: Apparently you did not read the HELP file for the Choice command. **The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the
key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice
listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in the name of ERRORLEVEL variable.

```
IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 GOTO copy
IF %errorlevel% EQU 2 GOTO end
IF %errorlevel% EQU 3 GOTO no_choice
```

The `/i` option is not necessary in this case...